# Contact Bit Mask

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

so I am using physics Body and contactbitmasks/physicscategories in my app but they aren't working right. I want the ball to reset when it hits a danger or for it to move on to the next level once it touches the goal. At the moment I have it set to print statements just for test reasons.

I have they all set up in the code but it still wont work. What is the problem?

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var ball = SKSpriteNode()
var danger1 = SKSpriteNode()
var danger2 = SKSpriteNode()
var goal = SKSpriteNode()


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    ball = self.childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode
    danger1 = self.childNode(withName: "danger1") as! SKSpriteNode
    danger2 = self.childNode(withName: "danger2") as! SKSpriteNode
    goal = self.childNode(withName: "goal") as! SKSpriteNode

    let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    border.friction = 0
    border.restitution = 0

    danger1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    danger1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory
    danger2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    danger2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory

    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width/2)
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.ballCategory
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory
    ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none

    goal.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    goal.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.goalCategory

    danger1.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    goal.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    danger2.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    danger2.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    danger1.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    goal.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    ball.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    setupPhysics()

}
func setupPhysics() {
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        ball.position.x = location.x
        ball.position.y = location.y
        print("x: \(ball.position.x), y: \(ball.position.y)")
    }
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}
}

extension GameScene: SKPhysicsContactDelegate {



func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    if contactMask == PhysicsCategories.ballCategory | PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory {
        print("Contact")
    } else if contactMask == PhysicsCategories.ballCategory | PhysicsCategories.goalCategory {
        print("Goal!")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Nobody even knows what PhysicsCategories.ballCategory and PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory are.

Comment: It straight up says its a SpriteNode? Don't think you need to know anything else. Unless I'm wrong but.....

Comment: Schmobr - your GameScene needs to be an `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` in addition to KoD’s answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your physics body for your danger zones have no sizes to them, so how is anything going to collide?

```
danger1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody() should be danger1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:danger1.size)
```

Now for some advanced notes, unless your sprites are actually moving, turn off isDynamic.  In the real world, your wall will never collide with the ball unless that wall is collapsing on top of the ball.

The cleanup should look something like this:

```
physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
ball = self.childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode
danger1 = self.childNode(withName: "danger1") as! SKSpriteNode
danger2 = self.childNode(withName: "danger2") as! SKSpriteNode
goal = self.childNode(withName: "goal") as! SKSpriteNode

let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
border.friction = 0
border.restitution = 0

danger1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:danger1.size)
danger1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory
danger1.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

danger2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:danger2.size)
danger2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory
danger2.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width/2)
ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.ballCategory
ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory | PhysicsCategories.goalCategory
ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none
ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
ball.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false

goal.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:goal.size)
goal.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.goalCategory
goal.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
//setupPhysics()  Remove this
```

Comment: Alrighty! I will try it once I get back to my coding. Thank for the help, I'll let you know if it worked or not :)

Comment: When I remove setupPhysics() Nothing gets printed/nothing happens with collisions. I changed the SKPhysicsBody with now allows items to be printed but if I change the print statement to something like `ball.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 550)` nothing happens. Also, nothing happens when the ball touches the goal still

Comment: did you move the contact delegate to the main function like I have listed here? Don't know your problem with goal

Comment: It says "Cannot assign value of type 'GameScene' to type 'SKPhysicsContactDelegate?'"

Comment: No idea what you did, this is your code, I just moved the line out of setup physics.  You somehow lost the delegate you used to have assigned to gamescene

Comment: I got the delegate to work in the top part of the code, I commented out the code at the bottom, not realizing I needed it. It still doesn't change the position of the ball though. Could it because of the way I'm moving it around?

Comment: I addressed your ball position problems in a different question.

Comment: Where can I find it

Comment: I've literally coded everything up to this point. I've been stuck on this for about a month now, not able to find anything that helps. All I'm trying to do is find a solution. I'm asking questions about your answer because it helped, but also didn't help. No need to be rude about this. I am new to coding and am trying to learn.